# update value in array of hash and return a json faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am currently working on a database API which is returning me the result of an ActiveRecord::Base class call. Right now when I required a data from the PostGres DB, I am using the following command:

```
 ApiResponse.select([:id, :ts, :response])
          .where(userid: 'toto')
          .limit(limit).to_a
```

This code is working find and I get a array of hash :

```
[
    [ 0] #<ApiResponse:0x007fb27e5d0c40> {
              :id => "7cbf6ce2-ec5e-41e0-8185-030f0a70b247",
              :ts => 2017-08-28 20:21:09 UTC,
              :response => {}}, ...
   ...

]
```

ApiResponse is just a class to access to the DB using ActiveRecord and defined as:

```
class ApiResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Right now, based on the result I have to run the below code to make it JSON and modify the ts field

```
 new_list = list.map do | e |
        {
            id: e['id'],
            ts: e['ts'].strftime("%F %T.%6N%z"),
            response: e['response']
        }
      end
```

This solution is not the best I think because I am running through a map (list is the result of the select command) to modify one field [ts] to match the date/time format and secondly, I am doing a

```
return new_list.to_json
```

the need of modify the date/time is because the PostGres DB use PostGres Date/Time format but ActiveRecord use ISO8601.

I do have 2 questions:

- Is there a faster way to parse all the array to apply the 'strftime' on each ts field? other than using map
- Is there a way to avoid using 'to_json' to_json is amazingly slow. For privacy, the response is null but in my code, it contains a lot of data which slow down the system.

Thanks

Comment: For first question, maybe make use of concurrency and map in parallel? With threads/concurrent-ruby/parallel-gem?

Comment: Did a little benchmark and it seems to_json called on an array is slower than map. So it wouldn't be changing the big O scale to add a map (both are ostensibly O(N) time). Some possibilities for your arsenal are [in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches), splitting the iteration over multiple threads (should probably use [mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html) if working with DB), or running the whole thing in a background job.